# Unable to compile dependencies on Xcode 13

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, compilation, beta

**The error:** "Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a non-zero exit code"

**Cause:** Simply messing with 2 Xcode installs by installing both Xcode 13 and Xcode 14 beta (with [Xcodes](https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/XcodesApp))

**Consequences:** First, Xcode lost connection with SwiftUI Previews device. Then compiling issues occur. All simulators were also gone from the list. *The error* keeps showing up for each dependency of the project.

**Unsuccessful attempts to solve this:**

- Uninstalling Xcode by moving it to trash, even performing a clean-uninstall with CleanMyMacX
- Manually wiping every Xcode-related file possible (browse the internet or perform a `find / -path "*Xcode*" 2> /dev/null`)
- Recreating a brand new project and moving all previous Swift files into it
- Removing and re-adding a bunch of times all my dependencies

**Solution:** Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution came from nowhere. I was trying to open Xcodes to check which versions were installed on the Mac when I accidentally pressed enter on the wrong Spotlight result: **Xcode Server Builder**.

I have no clue what that is, but I assume it's an embedded Xcode component used for compilation. That is, I opened it and it prompted me some **Accessibility access request**. I fulfilled it because why not, and I tried by curiosity to compile with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, **and it worked**.

About the empty list of simulators, I simply downloaded the latest available `iOS 15.4 Simulator`, and every device showed up as before.